# Creating a column being the multiple of others

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help. I have 2 columns from mysql query result - one with text, and another with decimal values.

Like this:

```
select desc, value 
from table a


|5,50 %     |   2984.59     |
|Subs       |   10951.70    |
|Isent      |   3973.17     |
|13,30 %    |   560.26      |
```

From the rows that have the %, I want to multiply the values and create a third result column, rounding up to two decimal places. See above

```
2984,59 * 0,055 = 164,15245
560,26 * 0,133 = 74,514
```

I need write a SQL query that show something like above.

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|5,50 % | 2984,59   | 164,16    |
|Subs   | 10951,70  | 0 or NULL |
|Isent  | 3973,17   | 0 or NULL |
|13,30% | 560,26    | 74,52     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

How can I do that?

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: Description || Value || multiple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to have floaring numbers in the first place, converting costs time

You have commas in your procentage, but mysql needs dots there

If value isn't always a number, you can use the mysql way to add a 0 0 to it, that remioves all non numerical characters

```
SELECT `desc`, `value`,  (REPLACE(`desc`,',','.') + 0)   *  `value` / 100 FROM val
```

| desc | value | (REPLACE(`desc`,',','.') + 0) * `value` / 100 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5,50 % | 2985 | 164.175 |
| Subs | 10952 | 0 |
| Isent | 3973 | 0 |
| 13,30 % | 560 | 74.48 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U7DMZhMd)

```
SELECT `desc`, `value`,  CEIL((REPLACE(`desc`,',','.') + 0)   *  `value`) / 100 FROM val
```

| desc | value | CEIL((REPLACE(`desc`,',','.') + 0) * `value`) / 100 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5,50 % | 2985 | 164.18 |
| Subs | 10952 | 0 |
| Isent | 3973 | 0 |
| 13,30 % | 560 | 74.48 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ouQoigZ1)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for help. It is almost what i need. I need to round the value. If third decimal place is diferente of 0, like 10,001, it need to round up to 10,01. How to complement the select in this case?

Comment: for your data it is enough to CEIL the resulting  multiplication, for more complex you need to mulitply and divide the correct 10 potention see my changed answer

Comment: You are greate! Thanks for help! Is 100% beautiful now